# How to access https URL for spring boot application

Tags: java, ssl, docker, https

I have a spring boot application which is hosted insight DOCKER.
for making it HTTPS I have applied:

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

It is not working i am getting could not get any response.